# Windows XP blue screen 0x8E error troubleshooting

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, memory, bsod

I get following blue screen after running my laptop for an hour...

```
A problem has been detected and windows has been shut down to prevent damage 
to your computer. [...]

Technical Information: *** STOP 0x0000008E (0xc0000005, 0x805B03F5, 0xF703DC7C, 0x00000000)

[...]
```

So how can I tell if this is faulty memory or some other hardware problem?

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite A45-S250.

Comment: i'm sorry, *"where can i buy..."* questions are offtopic here; Super User isn't a shopping site.  we *can* help you figure out what the trouble is, so i've edited your question to ask that.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that the stop code youve got is generally related to RAM, but not always so. Sometimes it can be caused by driver errors.
I would recommend reading this [About.com](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/stop0x0000008e.htm) on STOP codes. It has helped me in the past.

Also, to test for a RAM error try running the [Windows Memory Diagnostic](http://oca.microsoft.com/en/windiag.asp). This should help you figure out if it is a RAM problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel up to it, you can analyze your minidump files that are created when you get a bsod.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263

Or you can upload your .dmp files somewhere we can download them to analyze for you.

.